# sequential execution of an action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sequential

I have a need in which I have to return a record from the db and then update it so that the next time same record is not returned. This is required to make a live queue.
The problem I'm facing is that multiple calls are happening on my action at the same instant. Due to this, the same record is getting returned to multiple users.
I tried using lock! function but it puts a write lock and not the read lock.
Please suggest some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new column in by creating migration database say `read_locked` with type as boolean and default false ( just to keep it simple )

```
def change
  add_column :your_table_name, :read_locked, :boolean, default: false
end
```

Then use a default scope on Model

```
default_scope where(:read_locked => false)
```

Next time you want to lock some record you just have to change `read_locked` value to `true`

```
model_object.read_locked = true
model_object.save
```

All requests after that which are read_locked will be escaped

Hope this helps